# Oblique asymptote for: $f(t) = \frac{t^2\arctan t}{t-4}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

Say a function $$f(t) = \frac{t^2\arctan t}{t-4}$$

Obviously, this has a vertical asymptote at $t = 4$. However, the oblique asymptote, if there is one, I can't seem to find.

What I do is I put the oblique asymptotes equation to $y = kt + m$. I can then say that $k = \lim_{t\rightarrow\pm\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t}$ however, this equals infinity as $\lim_{t\rightarrow\pm\infty}t\arctan t = +\infty$.

Can I now safely assume there is no oblique asymptote? That's what I assumed until [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=asymptotes%20x%5E2*arctan%28x%29%2F%28x-4%29) told me otherwise.

---

#### Answer, as explained below by [Hippalectryon](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/150347/hippalectryon)

The mistake I made in the above text was to divide every term in my function by $t$, which is obviously incorrect. The correct equation after dividing $f(t)$ with $t$ is:

$$\frac{f(t)}{t} = \frac{t^2\arctan t}{t(t-4)}$$

Therefore we get

$$\displaystyle k = \lim_{t\rightarrow\pm\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t}=\lim_{t\rightarrow\pm\infty}\frac{t^2‌​\cdot\arctan(t)}{t\cdot(t-4)}=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\arctan(t)=\pi/2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle k = \lim_{t\rightarrow\pm\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t}=\lim_{t\rightarrow\pm\infty}\frac{t^2‌​\cdot\arctan(t)}{t\cdot(t-4)}=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\arctan(t)=\pi/2$

Comment: I feel like while all the important information is in this answer, just a little bit more effort to fit it into the context of the question would make it way clearer.

Comment: @BenMillwood While he made it clear to me, I will edit my post to make the details of his answer more clear for any future viewers.

Comment: @Hippalectryon Sorry, you shouldn't have had to ask for it. I was too focused on my maths. Thank you for the help.